# Umbraco get rendered content in OnPublish

Tags: umbraco7

I have an ApplicationEventHandler in Umbraco to catch publish events. We want to get the rendered html for some of our PublishedEntities and store them elsewhere ...

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

kind regards

Y.

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you wan't to save the output of a node on the publish event and store it? As a database record or to a file?

Comment: something like that, get the rendered content and store it in a database (displayed by another system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference ... Mark's answer is working but it downloads the full html.

Shorter would be to use

```
UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).RenderTemplate(node.id)
```